# Selecting relevant variables for regression in highly collinear data

Tags: multiple-regression, multicollinearity, partial-least-squares

I'm working on a supervised linear regression algorithm that maps units with large amounts of independent variables to a vector. Their labels correspond to one of four orthogonal vectors.
The variables are all painfully collinear and samples for the categories are very unbalanced (I'll ask how to fix this in another question). However, when I plot the different classes' means across all variables, I see some means diverge from other classes' in some variables. In one or two cases, their 1-standard-deviation bounds are non-overlapping for a couple classes.

**My question is this:**

Would regressing only on the variables with most distinct means yield better results and/or speed?

Comment: Is there some reason why you don't use penalized regression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to make predictions, then the collinearity doesn't necessarily make the model worse. As long as the model generalize well, e.g. in a cross-validation, then you don't need to worry about collinearity too much.

However, if you are trying to understand the relationships between each predictor and the response, then collinearity can result in misleading conclusions.